# Installing AWS CDK on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

According to the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/getting_started.html#getting_started_install), it should be possible to install the CDK package for Python development within CloudFormation.

I'm using a t2.micro Amazon Linux 2 : ami-0dd555eb7eb3b7c82 in eu-west-2 just for completeness.

The instructions state to run this : `python -m pip install aws-cdk-lib`
This fails with `"/usr/bin/python: No module named pip"`, but **replacing python with python3 resolves the issue** and the installation completes with this message:

```
Installing collected packages: attrs, typing-extensions, cattrs, six, python-dateutil, jsii, publication, constructs, aws-cdk-lib
Successfully installed attrs-21.4.0 aws-cdk-lib-2.13.0 cattrs-1.10.0 constructs-10.0.69 jsii-1.54.0 publication-0.0.3 python-dateutil-2.8.2 six-1.16.0 typing-extensions-4.1.1
```

Further to that, when doing >>>help('modules') in the python3 interpreter now shows aws_cdk  - so from that I'm assuming that all is good !!

The instructions indicate that the next step is to run python using the import - so I've created this :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import aws_cdk
print('hello')
```

However, running this returns *alot* of error messages. I've proceeded to look at the files mentioned and to try to figure out what I'm doing wrong but I've hit a dead end. I wonder if anybody has any ideas ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/importlib/resources.py", line 188, in path
    yield Path(reader.resource_path(resource))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_runtime.py", line 43, in load
    _kernel.load(assembly.name, assembly.version, os.fspath(assembly_path))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/__init__.py", line 269, in load
    self.provider.load(LoadRequest(name=name, version=version, tarball=tarball))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 338, in load
    return self._process.send(request, LoadResponse)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_utils.py", line 24, in wrapped
    stored.append(fgetter(self))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 333, in _process
    process.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 259, in start
    env=environ,
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'node': 'node'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./l", line 3, in <module>
    import aws_cdk
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aws_cdk/__init__.py", line 1051, in <module>
    from ._jsii import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aws_cdk/_jsii/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    import constructs._jsii
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/constructs/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from ._jsii import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/constructs/_jsii/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    "constructs", "10.0.69", __name__[0:-6], "constructs@10.0.69.jsii.tgz"
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_runtime.py", line 43, in load
    _kernel.load(assembly.name, assembly.version, os.fspath(assembly_path))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 161, in __exit__
    raise RuntimeError("generator didn't stop after throw()")
RuntimeError: generator didn't stop after throw()
Exception ignored in: <function _NodeProcess.__del__ at 0x7f3fc99ebb90>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 224, in __del__
    self.stop()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 281, in stop
    if not self._process.stdin.closed:
AttributeError: '_NodeProcess' object has no attribute '_process'
```

I also have a "home machine" running Centos and get very similar messages. However, I proceeded with an ec2 instance to make the problem more easily replicable and documentable. Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

Thankyou "9769953" - the answer appears to be that for AWS CDK python library to work you have to install the dependencies for node.

This [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67884868/installing-npm-on-amazon-linux-ami) has also helped.

For documentation - here is the method to install AWS CDK for python on Amazon Linux 2 - and other similar Linux distros.

a. Install Node Version manager.

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash
```

b. Activate nvm.

```
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

c. Install node.

```
nvm install node
```

d. Check versions (optional).

```
node -v
npm -v
```

e. Finally the python bit !

```
python3 -m pip install aws-cdk-lib
```

f. Run a Python program.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import aws_cdk
print('hello')
```

That's it.

Thankyou again to "9769953" and also to "CyberEternal".

Answer (score 1):

As stated on the linked page, you should first install the AWS CDK, which is done with `npm`. Which is the `node.js` package manager; the latter is very likely the `'node'` referred to in the error message, since it is an external (executable) file that is run through `subprocess`.

So install `node` and `npm` first (they probably come together), then proceed with install the Python AWS CDK.

Comment: I see what you mean - the way I have read that is that there are 5 possible installations for 5 different languages - I did not think you had to install CDK for every language just to support one.

Comment: That's how these things often work: one (large) mainstream package, and then interfaces in various languages on top of that. Among others, it is easier to maintain the core code.